# Django migrate --fake-initial reports relation already exist

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am trying to import an existing database into my **Django** project, so I run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`, but I get this error:

```
operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: ExcursionsManagerApp, GeneralApp, InvoicesManagerApp, OperationsManagerApp, PaymentsManagerApp, RatesMan
agerApp, ReportsManagerApp, ReservationsManagerApp, UsersManagerApp, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying GeneralApp.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookWebProject/IntellibookWebVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/back
ends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "GeneralApp_airport" already exists
```

Of course all the tables already exist in the database, that is the reason why I use `--fake-initial`, that is supposed to **fake** the creation of database objects.

Why is `migrate` attempting to create the table `GeneralApp__airport` instead of faking it?

Answer (score 2):

`--fake-initial` can't deal with any situation where some of the tables listed in the initial migration exist and some do not. So, if tables exist for some, but not all, of the `CreateModel()`s in the `operations` list in your `0001_initial.py`, `--fake-initial` does not apply and it tries to create tables for ALL of the models.

Does that make sense? Not to me...

Comment: The way it works doesn't make sense but knowing it saved the day! Finally realized why the migration is trying to create tables. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just by running the following [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) would solve the problem:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps you can follow to make migrations from an existing database. Firstly empty the django migration table from the database.

```sql
delete from django_migrations
```

1. Remove migrations from your migrations folder for the app

```sh
rm -rf <app>/migrations/
```

2. Reset the migration for builtin apps(like admin)

```sh
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

3. Create initial migration for each and every app

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations <app>
```

4. The final step is to create fake initial migrations

```sh
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```